# USB Keyboard not working after Macbook wakes up from sleep

Tags: keyboard

I have a standard Windows PC-compatible USB keyboard plugged into my Mac. It works just fine, but whenever I wake my Mac up from sleep, I am forced to unplug and replug the keyboard from USB to get it to work.

Comment: Details, details, details...

Comment: I don't see how this is not clear, hence I don't understand why it was closed. I have the same issue and a workaround I noticed is to wake the mac using the built in keyboard, then the usb keyboard works...

Answer (score 0):

I would reset both your PRAM/NVRAM and your SMC. See below for instructions.

**Reset your PRAM/NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). It may be worth you also resetting this. Here’s how to:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. **Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.** You have to make sure you press these keys before the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. **Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.**

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

**Reset the SMC**

Your computer's System Management Controller (SMC) can also be reset. However, the instructions for doing this on MacBooks differ depending on the type of battery they use. Since your question has specified the model, I've provided both sets of instructions below:

**For MacBook Pros, MacBook Airs, and MacBooks where you can’t remove the battery on your own (i.e. it's a built-in battery), here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (or power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the left side of the keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

**For MacBook Pros, MacBooks etc that you can remove the battery from, here’s what you do:**

1. Shut down your computer
2. **Disconnect** the MagSafe plug (or power cable) from the computer
3. Remove the battery
4. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> for 5 seconds and release
5. Put the battery back in
6. Reconnect the MagSafe cord (or power cable)
7. Turn your computer back on with the power button

Comment: With macOS Sierra 10.12.5, tried both but no luck...

Comment: MacOS Sierra 10.12.6, this partially worked in that if I started with no 'other' devices connected, and went one by one, testing both sleep and sleep after restart -- I could get the power failure to affect a device I didn't care to have on all the time (that is, working ok after computer wake from sleep).  So basically I made sure the keyboard was the first I plugged in after going through above steps.  My failure was moved from the keyboard (before) to an DAW / audio device (afterwards.)   Also, no idea if that's bad for the audio device, but I don't see it triggering the DAW to 'on' at all.